# Cómo agregar un botón asociado a un ID en cada fila de un datatable que se rellena a través de Ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatables

Estoy utilizando DataTables y encontré la manera de agregar un botón en la columna que necesito, el dilema es que no puedo concatenar el id que trae cada fila, he intentado de diferentes maneras y no me resulta, el código es el siguiente:
Realizo la petición por Ajax y le paso los parámetros a otra función con un foreach

```
function CargaTareas() {
    var xusuario  = $('#cbousuarios').val();        
    var xestado   = $('#cboestado').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= base_url();?>index.php/control/cicompras/docargatareas",
    dataType: 'json',
    dataSrc: '',
    data: {
        usuario: xusuario,
        estado: xestado
    }
    }).done(function(response){
        $.each(response, function(index, value){
            Llenar(response, index, value); 
        });
    });
}
```

Acá en la función Llenar recibo lo recopilado...

```
function Llenar(response, index, value) {
    var tablaTv = $('#productos').DataTable({
        pageLenght: 5,
        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, -1], [5, 10, 'Todos']],
        language: {
            ...
            }
        },
        destroy: true,
        data: response,
        columns: [
            {defaultContent: '<a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/control/cicompras/detalletarea/'+ ... +'">Ver</a>'},
            // {data: "numero"},
            {data: "fecha"},
            {data: "titulo"},
            {data: "glosa"},
            {data: "prioridad"},
            {data: "ufecha"},
            {data: "umensaje"}
        ]
        });
    }
```

En la columna defaultContent en "+ ...+ " necesito concatenar lo que trae {data: "numero"}, de tal manera no me funciona me muestra [object Object], y a este lo he parseado y no resulta.
También he concatenado "response[index].numero" y en todas las filas me concatena el id del último registro.
También he declarado fuera del DataTable una variable para concatenarla y tampoco me funciona... A alguien más le ha pasado? Pudieron solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola hay una funcion de los datatable para renderizar dentro de las columnas, segun [Documentacion render datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html) y por experiencia propia lo intentaria hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
function Llenar(response, index, value) {
var tablaTv = $('#productos').DataTable({
    pageLenght: 5,
    lengthMenu: [[5, 10, -1], [5, 10, 'Todos']],
    language: {
        ...
        }
    },
    destroy: true,
    data: response,
    columns: [
        {data: "fecha"},
        {data: "titulo"},
        {data: "glosa"},
        {data: "prioridad"},
        {data: "ufecha"},
        {data: "umensaje"},
        {title: "acciones"}//Nueva columna para dibujar botones
    ],
    columnDefs:[
       {
          targets:-1,
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
             console.log(data)//avegirua como acceder a tu id
             //data es la informacion que contiene cada fila
             //Accesiendo a data puedes obtener el id de cada columna
             let boton = `<a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/control/cicompras/detalletarea/${tuVariable}">Ver</a>`
             return boton
          }
       }
    ]
    });
}
```

`target` indica en que columna quieres que se renderize
las columnas las indicas como los indices de un arreglo, por ejemplo, [0]=primera columna  ...etc, o -1,-2,-3 si empiezas de derecha a izquierda
target:-1 porque en mi ejemplo es la ultima fila

de esta forma yo renderizo botones con el datatable, te recomiendo primero probar renderizar primero el boton, luego con console.log(data) veas de que manera puedes acceder a tu id.

Documentacion relacionada

[Data rendering datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html)

[Column defs datatable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

[columns render datatable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, me funcionó tal cual como pusiste el script... el data tomó el valor de la columna que le puse en el target que era la columna 0

Comment: un gusto poder ayudar.