# Agregar checkbox a celda DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy actualizando una tabla DataTable, en una de las columnas necesito agregar un checkbox de acuerdo a uno de los valores que recibo, una vez dibujada la tabla en la columna recibo el valor `[object Object]`, de esta forma actualizo la tabla:

```
function OnlyNotApproved(checkbox) {
    var table = $('#table_datable_CoorSf').DataTable();
    if (checkbox.checked)
    {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../AManager/GetOnlyNotApproval",
            contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            success: function (records) {
                table.clear();//Limpia tabla
                records.forEach(e => {
                    table.rows.add([{
                        0: e.idscrap,
                        1: e.fecha.substring(0, 10),
                        2: e.parte,
                        3: e.numparte,
                        4: e.causa,
                        5: e.defecto,
                        6: e.descripcion,
                        7: e.causa,
                        8: e.cantidad,
                        9: new Test(e.idteam),
                        10: '<a href="' + '/AManager/Delete_sf/' + e.idscrap +'"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>'
                    }]);
                });
                table.draw();//Dibuja tabla
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Al llenar el valor de la columna 9 uso la función `Test()` que es como sigue:

```
function Test(idteam) {
    var item;
    if (idteam == 6) {
        item =  '<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">';
    }
    else { item = ''; }
    return item;
}
```

La intención es que solo en ciertos registros dibuje un checkbox, la [documentación](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()#Examples) de DataTables menciona que si puede recibir una función para añadir un valor, pero no me funciona. Anexo una imagen como sigue:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

efectivamente `datatables` tiene una funcion para renderizar contenido dentro de sus celdas ([Aca la documentacion de render](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html)), lo que sucede en tu caso es que estas creando el datatable y luego netamente le envias datos para llenar sus filas, yo lo haria de la siguiente forma renderizando los checkbox al crear la tabla, **Pero debes tener presente como le envias tus datos al `DataTable`**, porque hay distintas formas de llenar un datatable pasandole la informacion como arreglo o como objeto, aca lo importante es la funcion (lo que responderia tu pregunta)`render` del datatable.

```
function OnlyNotApproved(checkbox) {
  let dataset = []
  if (checkbox.checked)
  {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "../AManager/GetOnlyNotApproval",
        contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (records) {
           $('#table_datable_CoorSf').DataTable({
              destroy: true,
              data: records,
              columns: [
                // {title: "parte", data: "Parte"} si pasas los datos como objeto
                {title: "N°"},
                {title: "Fecha"},
                {title: "Parte"},
                {title: "parte"},
                {title: "Analisis"},
                {title: "Defecto"},
                {title: "defecto"},
                {title: "causa"},
                {title: "cantidad"},
                {title: ""}//Nueva columna para dibujar checkbox
                {title: "icono de borrar"},
               ],
               columnDefs:[
               {
               targets:-2,
               render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
               //Aca depende mucho de como le pasas la data a la tabla, si como arreglo o como objeto.
               //supongamos que lo pasas con un arreglo bidimensional
               //indice de la fila
               let indiceFila = meta.row
               //record[indiceFila][8] a modo de ejemplo
               if (records[indiceFila][8]) 
                 item =  '<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">';
               
               else  
                 item = ''; 
               return item;
               }//Fin de la funcion render
              }]
          });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

> Lo que hace render es tomar la data que le envias, ya sea desde el arreglo original, o desde la informacion de la fila y ahi puedes gestionar lo que quieres renderizar, html en este caso

con `target:-2` seleccionas la columna a renderizar, en este caso es -2 porque la tomo de derecha a izquierda, pero si fuese numeros positivos seria usar su indice por ejemplo target:0, primera columna, target:1 segunda y asi..

Te recomiendo que le hagas un console.log() a los atributos que le pasas a la funcion render.

Espero te sirva y aca te dejo documentacion sobre los datatables.

Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/555015/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-un-bot%C3%B3n-asociado-a-un-id-en-cada-fila-de-un-datatable-que-se-relle/555023#555023) tiene mas detalles tal vez te sirva

[Documentacion render datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html)

[Documentacion colum defs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)